# Python's 2.7 socket.timeout behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

Below are two simple python functions. First tries to connect to `test.com` domain on 666 (host name is valid but port is not). Second tries to connect to `imap.mail.outlook.com` on port 993 (host name is valid, but looks like not for public use/access).

```
def fn_outlook(timeout):
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("imap.mail.outlook.com", 993), timeout=timeout)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass


def fn_test(timeout):
    try:
        socket.create_connection(("test.com", 666), timeout=timeout)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
```

And here are execution time for that function with different timeouts:

```
In [14]: %time fn_test(1)
CPU times: user 644 µs, sys: 1.07 ms, total: 1.71 ms
Wall time: 1 s

In [15]: %time fn_test(2)
CPU times: user 589 µs, sys: 1.15 ms, total: 1.74 ms
Wall time: 2 s

In [16]: %time fn_outlook(2)
CPU times: user 838 µs, sys: 2.24 ms, total: 3.08 ms
Wall time: 7.15 s

In [17]: %time fn_outlook(4)
CPU times: user 705 µs, sys: 1.18 ms, total: 1.88 ms
Wall time: 12 s

In [18]: %time fn_test(4)
CPU times: user 483 µs, sys: 795 µs, total: 1.28 ms
Wall time: 4.42 s
```

For `test.com` connection will timeout after the ~same time as was specified in `timeout` argument. But for `imap.mail.outlook.com` things are getting interesting -- socket connection ignores timeout argument. To be precise - not ignores, but rather always timeouts connection after some greater period of time.

I may suppose that this behavior originates from `imap.mail.outlook.com` server,  not from socket module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can unify your to functions into:

```
def fn_connect(host, port, timeout):
    try:
        s = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout=timeout)
    except socket.timeout:
        return None
    else:
        return s
```

and call them like:

```
IMAP_HOST = "imap.mail.outlook.com"
IMAP_PORT = 993
TEST_HOST = "test.com"
TEST_PORT = 666
s1 = fn_connect(IMAP_HOST, IMAP_PORT, 2)
s2 = fn_connect(TEST_HOST, TEST_PORT, 1)
#and so on....
```

I returned the socket to be able to close it properly afterwards (if `not None`).

The problem lies in how the underlying socket mechanism resolves hostnames; `create_connection` calls [getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), and for each address returned it tries to create a socket and connect to it (**and each socket has the very timeout you specified**). So, the results for your 2 addresses:

- *TEST_HOST*, *TEST_PORT*

  ```
  socket.getaddrinfo("test.com", 666)
  [(2, 0, 0, '', ('69.172.200.235', 666))]
  ```
- *IMAP_HOST*, *IMAP_PORT*

  ```
  socket.getaddrinfo("imap.mail.outlook.com", 993)
  [(2, 0, 0, '', ('207.46.163.247', 993)),
   (2, 0, 0, '', ('207.46.163.138', 993)),
   (2, 0, 0, '', ('207.46.163.215', 993))]
  ```

As you can see, for *IMAP_HOST*, *IMAP_PORT* it returns 3 separate addresses (while for *TEST_HOST*, *TEST_PORT* it only returns one). Since you specified that none of it works it will attempt to connect to all of them resulting in a general timeout ~3 times bigger than you specified.